# Type conversion failing after dynamically constructing INSERT statement?

Tags: php, sql, json, postgresql, type-conversion

I am attempting to dynamically create an INSERT statement based on JSON key/value pairs where the $key is the database field of string or integer data type and $value is an integer or string. I haven't had issues inserting numeric strings into Postgres before but it is failing.

Example:

```
$json = '{"stringField":"string","intString":"42"}';
$columns = $values = '';
foreach (json_decode($json, true) as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != NULL) {
        $columns .= $key . ', ';        
        $values .=  "'" . $value . "', ";
    }
}
$query = ('INSERT INTO table ('.rtrim($columns, ', ').') VALUES ('.trim($values, ', ').');');
```

Comment: Postgres will accept both `42` and `'42'` for a numeric field in an `INSERT` statement, so you could just add the quotes unconditionally.

Comment: This site prefers to keep questions and answers separate, so rather than adding a solution into the "question" field, you are encouraged to either click the "accept" tick mark against one of the answers, or [answer your own question and accept that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @NickBarnes you are correct which is why I was so confused. It turned out to be a _float_ numeric string that was causing the error. Solution posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that one of the values was actually a *float* numeric string failing on insert into an integer field, rounding the value if it is a numeric string solves this. The `is_numeric` check avoids string fields being converted to `0`.

**Solution:**

```
$json = '{"stringField":"string","floatString":"42.0","intString":"42"}';
$columns = $values = '';
foreach (json_decode($json, true) as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != NULL) {
        $columns .= $key . ', ';        
        $values .= is_numeric($value) ?  round($value) . "," : "'" . $value . "', ";
    }
}
$query = ('INSERT INTO table ('.rtrim($columns, ', ').') VALUES ('.trim($values, ', ').');');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is cleaner PHP:

```
$json = '{"stringField":"string","numberField":"42"}';
$columns = $values = '';
foreach (json_decode($json, true) as $key => $value) {
    if ($value !== NULL) {
        $columns .= $key . ', ';
        $values .= is_numeric($value) ? $value : "'" . $value . "', ";
    }
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO table ('.rtrim($columns, ', ').') VALUES ('.trim($values, ', ').');';
```

Please think about escaping your values.

Comment: The null conditional is needed in this particular case to avoid empty string values.

Comment: If it fits your needs please accept my answer as the valid answer

Comment: In this case I need the type-converting comparison `!=` to catch empty strings (along with `NULL` & `undefined` values). `"" !== NULL` evaluates to true.

Comment: you can replace `!== null` with `!$value` and it will catch `NULL` and empty strings

Comment: `(!$value)` will not catch  `""` which is also `false`,
`($value)` will not catch `" "` as any string evaluates to `true`,
`($value !== NULL)` is a strict comparison so it will not also not catch `" "`,
`($value != NULL)` will do the conversion and catch all desired cases